# How can I deploy my website from Git on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, git, ssh, ftp

I am trying to be more efficient in my work and take steps to stray away from SFTP.

I see services like "Deployhq" or "Docker" but they are not free.

I am hoping to automated myself in the idea that I just type in "git push" in my command line, and it would automatically deploy to my server as it pushes to git?

Does anyone have an idea on where to go? I look into Jenkin CI/CD but I am not sure if that is the correct direction.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Docker is free. And your question is off-topic: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly going to depend on your hosting company I believe.  Some companies allow you to set up a git deploy usually through some form of control panel.

If you are hosting the site yourself or have access to the server and can ssh/install git, you can clone the repo to the server and set up a hook so that the server will pull changes whenever you push up to the remote repository.

Here are some good links on how git hooks work and how to create one:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks